# Changing From UIViewController to a ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, subclass

When Selecting a new class instead of setting it to be a subclass of ViewController I set the subclass to be of UIViewController. Is there anyway I can change this back without creating the classes again

```
@interface AddLevel1ViewController : UIViewController
```

what I want is

```
 @interface AddLevel1ViewController : ViewController
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is... Just change the text to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The File->New->File... workflow doesn't do anything special behind the scenes. The single line in the header (.h) file beginning with `@interface` defines what your class subclasses. Just change the class name to what you want. You'll need to make sure you've `#import`ed that class as well.

So, as you've said, change:

`@interface AddLevel1ViewController : UIViewController`

to:

`@interface AddLevel1ViewController : ViewController`

and `#import "ViewController.h"` at the top of the file.